# How can I generate a folder with the last X files added?

Tags: linux, file, bash, directory

So I have a huge folder full subfolders with tons of files, and I add files to it all the time.

I need a subfolder in the root of that folder with a symlink of the last 10-20 files added so that I can quickly find the things I recently added. This is located on a NAS, but I have a linux box running Arch connected through NFS, so I assume the best way is to run a bash script with a find command followed by a loop of `ln -sf`, but I can't do it safely without help.

Comment: So your real question is "will you write me a bash script that does X"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is required:

```
mkdir -p subfolder
find /dir/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -n 10 | cut -d' ' -f2- | while IFS= read -r file ; do ln -s "$file" subfolder ; done
```

Which will create symlinks in `subfolder` pointing to the 10 most recently modified files in the directory tree rooted at `/dir/`

Comment: Well, that seems to have worked perfectly! Thanks! Made it into a quick bash script, and cron'ed it at 10 minute intervals!

Comment: Note that I had to change to hardlinks in order to open the files on OS X over NFS.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a shell function like:

```
recent() { ls -lt ${1+"$@"} | head -n 20; }
```

which will give you a listing of the 20 most recent items in the specified directories, or the current directory if no arguments are given.